# Docker Pytest containers stay up after completing testing process

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, pytest

I've set my django project and now I'm trying to test it with pytest. What is issue running pytest withing my containers doesn't kill it at the end of the process. So at the end of day I'm stuck with multiple running containers from pytest and often postgreSql connection problems.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    license_server:
        build: .
        command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && gunicorn LicenseServer.wsgi --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"
        depends_on:
            - postgres
        volumes:
            - .:/code
        environment:
            DATABASE_NAME: "${DATABASE_NAME}"
            DATABASE_USER: "${DATABASE_USER}"
            DATABASE_PASSWORD: "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
            DATABASE_PORT: "${DATABASE_PORT}"
            DATABASE_HOST: "${DATABASE_HOST}"
        env_file: .env
        ports:
            - "8000:8000"
        restart: always
    postgres:
        build: ./postgres
        volumes:
          - ./postgres/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
            DATABASE_NAME: "${DATABASE_NAME}"
            DATABASE_USER: "${DATABASE_USER}"
            DATABASE_PASSWORD: "${DATABASE_PASSWORD}"
            DATABASE_PORT: "${DATABASE_PORT}"
            DATABASE_HOST: "${DATABASE_HOST}"
        command: "-p 8005"
        env_file: .env
        ports:
           - "127.0.0.1:8005:8005"
        restart: always
    nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
      container_name: nginx1
      ports:
        - "8001:80"
      volumes:
        - .:/code
        - ./config/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      depends_on:
        - license_server
```

What I want to achieve is automatically closing containers after the testing process is finished.

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by pytest not being killed? And honestly it should not run in the docker, it is suppose to run in either in a CI before running the docker build to see if the code is deploy-able, or run in your local machine. If you are running docker as a part of development, then consider running it separately via `docker exec <Container ID> /bin/sh -c "python manage.py test"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have `restart: always` they will just keep restarting when all the processes spawned by the command have exited. Even when you try to kill the running containers yourself they will tend to restart (which can be a nuisance). Try removing `restart: always` from your service descriptions.

For more info, check the [docker-compose.yml reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#restart)